# What does the values of the Array returned by getByteFrequencyData() mean?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

I'm a little bit confused what exactly all the **values** of the **Uint8Array** retured by `getByteFrequencyData()` mean/represent?

How can I understand their value? And why are most of the first values defined and the later ones are most 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest spec explains [getByteFrequencyData](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AnalyserNode-getByteFrequencyData-void-Uint8Array-array) in more detail.  Basically, it's the magnitude of the FFT of the data converted to dB and scaled to a byte value between 0 and 255.  If the later values are 0, it's because there is very little frequency content there.